# How to retrieve the contents of entry and text widget and assign it to a variable in tkinter using python

Tags: python, tkinter

Well I have the following code which I wrote for creating a gui based email client using python.I used tkinter.I want that the text the user writes in the entry widget gets assigned to the variables sender,password,receiver,message.
I have used entry widget for getting the values of sender,password,receiver and text widget for the message .How to do so?I tried many methods(like the get method,the textvariable method) for this but its not getting executed.I am a newbie and hence would prefer an answer which does not involve classes.Please reply soon!Its urgent.Thanks for your help.I am just showing you what I did in case of assigning value to variable sender but i want this for all the four variables.

```
import smtplib
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


def Composemail(sender,password,receivers,message):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.connect('smtp.gmail.com',587) # for eg. host = 'smtp.gmail.com', port = 587
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        #smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        #smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Sending Mail information","Mail sent.")
    except smtplib.SMTPException, error:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Sending Mail information","Sending Mail failed.Try again  later.")

a=Tk()
a.title("MailsNow-A new place for sending emails")
a.geometry("1000x700")
b=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="From")
b.pack()
sender=StringVar() #the problem starts here
c=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100,textvariable=sender)
c.pack()    
d=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="Password")
d.pack()
e=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100,show="*")
e.pack()
password='abc'
f=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="To")
f.pack()
receivers = 'abc@gmail.com'
g=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100)
g.pack()
h=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="Subject")
h.pack()
i=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100)
i.pack()
j=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="Type your email here")
j.pack()
k=Text(a,bd=5,height=20,width=100)
k.pack()
message = """From: From Person <abc@gmail.com>#I want to know how to do the same for text #widget too
To: To Person <xyz@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

Hi , now I can send you emails using this......hurrah1!using Sending mail transfer protocol by a python 
code!!!!
"""   
l=Button(a,
text="Sendmail",bg="Purple",activebackground="Yellow",
command=lambda:Composemail(sender,password,receivers,message))
l.pack()
a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `get` on your StringVars - so your call to `ComposeMail` is `ComposeMail(sender.get() ` and so on for your other StringVar instances?

Comment: I did so but it was also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, you don't need to use `StringVar`.  This should be what you want:

```
import smtplib
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

def Composemail(sender,password,receivers,message):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.connect('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Sending Mail information","Mail sent.")
    # Just a tip, "error" isn't defined yet so it will blow up.
    except smtplib.SMTPException, error:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Sending Mail information","Sending Mail failed.Try again  later.")

a=Tk()
a.title("MailsNow-A new place for sending emails")
a.geometry("1000x700")
b=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="From")
b.pack()
c=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100)
c.pack()
d=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="Password")
d.pack()
e=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100,show="*")
e.pack()
f=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="To")
f.pack()
g=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100)
g.pack()
h=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="Subject")
h.pack()
i=Entry(a,bd=5,width=100)
i.pack()
j=Label(a,fg="Purple",text="Type your email here")
j.pack()
k=Text(a,bd=5,height=20,width=100)
k.pack()

def getstuff():
    # You can retrieve the text entered into an entrybox using the get method
    sender=c.get()
    password=e.get()
    receivers=g.get()
    subject=i.get()
    # Since textboxes are multiline, I have to tell it what text to get.
    # 0.0,END is saying "get everything from start to finish".
    message=k.get(0.0,END)

    # One thing I noted was that you are not sending the subject to
    # Composemail.  Is this what you want?
    Composemail(sender,password,receivers,message)

l=Button(a, text="Sendmail",bg="Purple",activebackground="Yellow",
command=getstuff)
l.pack()

a.mainloop()
```

When you click the "Sendmail" button, everything you entered into the application is gathered and sent to `Composemail`.  From there, you can do whatever you want with it.

p.s.  I threw out some of your code so I could work with your problem better.

Comment: Thanks a billion sir!You really solved my problem.The code is working fine and work is being done but I have a doubt.I also tried doing a thing like this where I used the get method.But in that I didn't create a function like getstuff().I did sender=c.get() without creating the function but then it was not working.Please tell the reason for that.

Comment: @user2504528: Very simple friend: when you were doing `sender=c.get()` before without a function, it was getting called only once upon launching the script (and, since nothing had been entered yet, it would get nothing).  After that, it would never be called again.  Putting it in a function however allows it to be called _each time_ the "sendmail" button is pressed.  So, each time you press the button, `getstuff` is called, which in turn executes `sender=c.get()`.

Comment: @iCodez---I also want to ask you how to mail this to multiple receivers at a tym as the variable receiver is getting the address of only the first receiver